# Error of quadratic interpolation in an equidistant table

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

> Show that the truncation error of quadratic interpolation in an equidistant table is bounded by  $$\frac{h^3}{9\cdot3^{0.5}}\max f''' (x)$$

I have gotten to nothing because i don't seem to understand quadratic interpolation errors unlike linear interpolation errors.

Comment: I have edited, partially heavily, your question. Please check that the corrections conform with your original task, especially that the subscript "$m$" was originally three dashes of the third derivative.

Comment: Write down the interpolation formula and apply Taylor's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to get the interpolation error

In the form of the Newton interpolation, the quadratic interpolation polynomial centered at $x_k$ can be written as
$$
p_2(x)=f(x_{k-1})+f[x_{k-1},x_k](x-x_{k-1})+f[x_{k-1},x_k,x_{k+1}](x-x_{k-1})(x-x_k).
$$
Fixing some point $z$, the cubic interpolation polynomial with this extra node can be written as
$$
p_3(x)=p_2(x)+f[x_{k-1},x_k,x_{k+1},z](x-x_{k-1})(x-x_k)(x-x_{k-1}).
$$
As this is exact at the nodes, $p_3(z)=f(z)$ or
$$
f(z)=p_2(z)+f[x_{k-1},x_k,x_{k+1},z](z-x_{k-1})(z-x_k)(z-x_{k-1}).
$$
The mean value formula for divided differences then gives
$$
f[x_{k-1},x_k,x_{k+1},z]=\frac16f'''(\zeta)
$$

#### The maximum of the error in the interval

The [interpolation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lagrange_Polynomial_Approximation) [error](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1516715/115115) for the quadratic polynomial interpolating at the points $x_{k-1},x_k,x_{k+1}$ and their tabulated values is bounded by
$$
|f(x)-p_2(x)|\le\frac{1}6\max_{\zeta\in[x_{k-1},x_{k+1}]}|f'''(\zeta)||\cdot(x-x_{k-1})(x-x_k)(x-x_{k+1})|
$$
If $x\in8x_{k-1},x_{k+1}]$ is parametrized as $x_k+sh$ with $s\in[-1,1]$, then this bound becomes
$$
\frac{h^3}6\|f'''\|_{[x_{k-1},x_{k+1}]}\cdot |s-s^3|.
$$
The local maxima of the non-constant factor in $[-1,1]$ are located at $s=\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}$, which will result in the claimed bound.

#### Use in table look-up may give smaller errors

If implemented as a procedure, the input $x$ would be associated to the closest table node $x_k$ with $|x-x_k|\le\frac h2$ as center node in the interpolation.
But the maximizing points $s$ are outside the interval $[-\frac12,\frac12]$. To get an approximate value for the point $x=x_k+\frac1{\sqrt3}h$ from the table, one would use the interpolation polynomial based on the triple centered at $x_{k+1}$. Thus the maximum error for the more realistic procedure is at $s=\pm\frac12$.